# Large amount of crashes on core data managedobjectmodel

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobjectmodel

Using Fabrics crash analytics or "Crashlytics" I am getting a large amount of crashes (I assume BAD_ACCESS) from the following method/property :

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    var modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("<app_name>", withExtension: "momd")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!
}()
```

By large amount I mean 275 crashes for 150 users in just one day. It is working fine on most devices but I did have the issue once with my simulator and I reset the contents and restarted my machine and the error went away.

I am hoping there is a better solution than having to tell people who are calling our tech support.

Returned by fabric

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  <app_name>                     0x100082f9c specialized AppDelegate.(persistentStoreCoordinator.getter).(closure #1) (AppDelegate.swift:314)
1  <app_name>                     0x10007e678 AppDelegate.saveContext() -> () (AppDelegate.swift:340)
2  <app_name>                     0x10007e014 @objc AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate(UIApplication) -> () (AppDelegate.swift)
3  UIKit                          0x1949f0d48 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 244
4  UIKit                          0x194bef268 __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.2093 + 792
5  UIKit                          0x194bf2a18 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
6  UIKit                          0x194be4ab4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 528
7  UIKit                          0x194958724 _afterCACommitHandler + 132
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18e7e49a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18e7e2628 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18e7e2a74 __CFRunLoopRun + 956
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18e712d94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
12 GraphicsServices               0x19017c074 GSEventRunModal + 100
13 UIKit                          0x1949cb130 UIApplicationMain + 208
14 <app_name>                     0x100069940 main (AppDelegate.swift:43)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x18d72159c start + 4
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? We are using Swift 2.3 currently converting to Swift 3.1.

The function is called when **applicationWillTerminate()** is called. The modelURL is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I also observed similar situation in my app. I once or twice had this error on simulator.

According to my observations it's happens when user swipes app from App Switcher (and removes it from memory). My guess is that `Bundle.main` becomes unavailable earlier and app cannot finish something.

I didn't have any contact from users that observed that. It looks like that they can't observe this because they just killed the app. So it's probably harmless (even if annoying).